# Close all file descriptors in bash

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptors

Is there a way to close all the open file descriptors, without having an explicit list of them beforehand?

Comment: All of *which* file descriptors? Every process has some open.

Comment: What are "all the open file descriptors"? 0, 1, and 2? Or do you have many more? If so, where did they come from?

Comment: Aren't the file descriptors closed automatically when the script finishes?

Comment: This is useful to know for the situation when you fork a shell-script, and thus need to close all the parents sockets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To answer literally, to close *all* open file descriptors for `bash`:

```
for fd in $(ls /proc/$$/fd); do
  eval "exec $fd>&-"
done
```

However this really isn't a good idea since it will close the basic file descriptors the shell needs for input and output. If you do this, none of the programs you run will have their output displayed on the terminal (unless they write to the `tty` device directly). If fact in my tests closing `stdin` (`exec 0>&-`) just causes an interactive shell to exit.

What you may actually be looking to do is rather to close all file descriptors that are not part of the shell's basic operation. These are 0 for `stdin`, 1 for `stdout` and 2 for `stderr`. On top of this some shells also seem to have other file descriptors open by default. In `bash`, for example, you have 255 (also for terminal I/O) and in `dash` I have 10, which points to `/dev/tty` rather than the specific `tty`/`pts` device the terminal is using. To close everything apart from 0, 1, 2 and 255 in `bash`:

```
for fd in $(ls /proc/$$/fd); do
  case "$fd" in
    0|1|2|255)
      ;;
    *)
      eval "exec $fd>&-"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Note also that `eval` is required when redirecting the file descriptor contained in a variable, if not `bash` will expand the variable but consider it part of the command (in this case it would try to `exec` the command `0` or `1` or whichever file descriptor you are trying to close).

**NOTE:** Also using a glob instead of `ls` (eg `/proc/$$/fd/*`) seems to open an extra file descriptor for the glob, so `ls` seems the best solution here.

#### Update

For further information on the portability of `/proc/$$/fd`, please see [Portability of file descriptor links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links). If `/proc/$$/fd` is unavailable, then a drop in replacement for the `$(ls /proc/$$/fd)`, using `lsof` (if that is available) would be `$(lsof -p $$ -Ff | grep f[0-9] | cut -c 2-)`.

Comment: `/proc` is only available under Linux.

Comment: @chepner you would be right if you said that `/proc/PID/fd` is not very portable. But saying that `/proc` is only available under Linux is **not** a correct statement.

Comment: Some websites use the `<&-` form, is it any different/needed?

Comment: @LorenzoPistone, the direction makes no difference when closing a descriptor, so either form can be used.

Comment: `for fd in $(ls /proc/$$/fd| grep -v [012]); do exec {fd}>&-; done`   # Filtering out std streams

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of Bash (4.1 and onward, year 2009 and later) you **can** specify the file descriptor to close using a shell variable:

```
for fd in $(ls /proc/$$/fd/); do
    [ $fd -gt 2 ] && exec {fd}<&-
done
```

The feature had been in Korn shell already (since 1993?) but apparently took some time to make its way into Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Clear all file descriptors except i/o/e of the current shell, but also excludes the ones provided as arguments

```bash
clear_fds() {
for fd in $(compgen -G "/proc/$BASHPID/fd/*"); do
    fd=${fd/*\/}
        if [[ ! " $* " =~ " ${fd} " ]]; then
            case "$fd" in
                0|1|2|255)
                ;;
                *)
                    eval "exec $fd>&-"
                    ;;
            esac
        fi
done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way

```
eval exec {0..255}">&-"
```

`exec {0..255}">&-"` expands to the `exec 0>&- 1>&- ... 255>&-` literal string, according to `Brace Expansion` (see `Brace Expansion` chapter in `man bash` for more info), then `eval` actually evaluates the command

Answer (score 1):

No. The kernel can close only one FD at a time, and bash does not have "group commands" for FDs.

```
for fd in $(ls -1 /proc/27343/fd); do echo exec $fd">&"-; done
```

Remove the `echo` and the `"` after testing.

If this is not for the shell itself but for a command to be run then you can use `nohup`.

Comment: The file descriptor used by `>&-` cannot be a parameter; the redirection is parsed prior to parameter expansion.

Comment: @chepner nowadays `exec {fd}>&-` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without subshell `$(....)` and without referring parent process,
furthermore, if you are using Bash 4.1+, you can do it without `eval`.

```
for path in /proc/self/fd/*; do
  fd=${path##*/} # get name part
  exec {fd}>&-
done
```

More resonable implementation should exclude the stdin,stdout,stderr, left them to the caller side.

```
for path in /proc/self/fd/*; do
  fd=${path##*/} # get name part
  ((fd < 3)) || exec {fd}>&-
done
```

Comment: This answer is the fastest in general case. In special case if you want to close specific descriptors, that you know beforehand, then this is faster: `eval exec {3..9}">&-"` or `eval exec {0,1,2,9,11,255}">&-"`

Answer (score 0):

Another way without "eval" at all, is to use the form:

```
$ exec {var_a}>> file.txt
$ echo $var_a
10
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/10
l-wx------ 1 0 0 64 Dec 11 18:32 /proc/self/fd/10 -> /run/user/0/tmp/file.txt
$ echo "aaaaa" >&$var_a
$ cat file.txt
aaaaa
$ exec {var_a}>&-
$ ls /proc/self/fd/10
ls: cannot access '/proc/self/fd/10': No such file or directory
```

Comment: But this doesn't close **all** file descriptors.

Comment: Indeed. You'll have to exec in a loop like explained in the previous replies... It was just to point the fact that "eval" is not mandatory here and that we can keep the same logic to close it than to open it... Man pages are really not clear about this...