# Does Posix require any devices?

Tags: devices, posix

Does Posix require any devices? For example, `/dev/urandom`, `/dev/zero` or `/dev/null`?

I suspect not because of non-*nix OSes, but wanted to ask for completeness.

Comment: `/dev/null /dev/tty` ... and ... maybe that's it. It also requires the `/tmp` path. I know because I once asked a [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123602/52934). Oh, and `/dev/console`.

Answer (score 16):

POSIX general defines three special files:

- /dev/tty
- /dev/console
- /dev/null

In addition, `/` and `/tmp` are also defined by POSIX.

`/dev/zero`, `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` are defined in some [UNIX-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) operating systems. Some operating systems may not define them, or implement with different names.

**Note**

- [POSIX Directory Structure and Files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap10.html)
- [/dev/zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/zero)
- [/dev/random](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random)

Comment: I've seen `nul` and `console` on Windows, but I don't believe I've ever seen `tty`.

Comment: @noloader: Windows implement only the first version of POSIX standard. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_POSIX_subsystem

Comment: @noloader Windows's `nul` and `console` aren't related to Unix's `/dev/null` and `/dev/console` except in some indirect historical way. The names `nul` and `console` were inherited from [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) (which didn't have directories); CP/M/DOS/Windows's `nul` means the same thing as unix's `/dev/null` but `console` under DOS and Windows means a serial port, not the console like on unix systems. If you run an application in Windows's POSIX subsystem (or in another POSIX implementation on top of Windows), you will get `/dev/null`, `/dev/tty` and `/dev/console`.

Comment: To add to @Gilles explanation, basically Windows/Dos's `console` is to UNIX's `/dev/tty1` or Plan9's `/dev/console`. But historically meant the keyboard and mouse or stdin. While serial ports was over COM{1..4} or AUX, and parallel ports was over LPT{1-4}.