# Redirecting a string to current TTY

Tags: tty, c

I have some code:

```
char *tty_name = ttyname(STDIN_FILENO);
char command[255] = "/usr/sbin/writevt -t "; strcpy(stpcpy(command + 21, tty_name), " -T ' \r'"); system(command);
```

It writes a "space" and a "carriage return" to the current TTY.
Which works fine for my uses. But, i'm wondering if there is a simpler way of achieving this? I've tried this:

```
echo -e " \r > $(tty)"
```

But, it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do (assuming the echo accepts the -n as "do not print a trailing new line") :

```
echo -ne " \r" > "$(tty)"
```

Redirections (`>`) do not work inside quotes.

A "one line" example:

```
$ echo -n Test; echo -ne " \r " > $(tty); echo "New string"
New string
```

A more robust (portable) solution is to use printf:

```
$ printf Test;     printf ' \r' > "$(tty)"    ; echo "New string"
```

And (as [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html#tag_10_01)) use the common `/dev/tty` as the name of the process tty:

```
printf ' \r' > /dev/tty
```

Related: [Does Posix require any devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146738/265604)

Comment: Awesome. It's working. Thank you. I'm closing this thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead `open(2)` `/dev/tty` and write to that:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ttyfd;
    if ((ttyfd = open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY)) == -1)
        err(1, "open /dev/tty failed");
    printf("test1\n");
    dprintf(ttyfd, " \rxxx");
    printf("test2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

(`" \r"` by itself may not be visible as it could be clobbered by the next written line.)