# Reading from file descriptor fails

Tags: file-descriptors

This question is about reading and writing on a file descriptor. See the following example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

file='somefile'

# open fd 3 rw
exec 3<> "$file"

# write something to fd 3
printf "%s\n%s\n" "foo" "bar" >&3

# reading from fd 3 works
cat "/proc/$$/fd/3"

# only works if the printf line is removed
cat <&3

exit 0
```

This script outputs:

```
foo
bar
```

Expected output:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Opening and writing to the file descriptor succeeds. So does reading via `proc/$$/fd/3`. But this [is not portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123659/12779). `cat <&3` doesn't output anything. However, it works when the file descriptor is not being written to (e.g. uncomment the `printf` line).

Why doesn't `cat <&3` work and how to read the entire contents from a file descriptor portably (POSIX shell)?

Comment: After `printf "%s\n%s\n" "foo" "bar" >&3`, fd 3 has a read/write pointer at byte 8 of the file. Do you want `cat <&3` to start reading from the beginning of the file rather than from byte 8?

Comment: Yes, it should start at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cat <&3` does exactly what it's supposed to do, namely read from the file until it reaches the end of the file. When you call it, the file position on the file descriptor is where you last left it, namely, at the end of the file. (There's a single file position, not separate ones for reading and for writing.)

`cat /proc/$$/fd/3` doesn't do the same thing as `cat <&3`: it opens the same file on a different descriptor. Since each file descriptor has its own position, and the position is set to 0 when opening a file for reading, this command prints the whole file and doesn't affect the script.

If you want to read back what you wrote, you need to either reopen the file or rewind the file descriptor (i.e. set its position to 0). There's no built-in way to do either in a POSIX shell nor in most sh implementations ([there is one in ksh93](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182993)). There is only one utility that can seek: [`dd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dd.html), but it can only seek forward. (There are other utilities that may skip forward but that doesn't help.)

I think the only portable solution is to remember the file name and open it as many times as necessary. Note that if the file isn't a regular file, you might not be able to seek backwards anyway.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 3>file
exec 4<file

printf "%s\n" "foo" "bar" >&3
cat <&4
```

By using separate file descriptors for reading and writing you get separate positions in the file. Writing doesn't change the reading position.

Comment: But `file` is opened twice, so that you may have a race condition. I don't know whether this matters for the OP. But I wonder if there is a way to change the reading position (i.e. do a `seek`), possibly with some shell extension.

Comment: @vinc17 Why should there be a race condition with two descriptors but not with one? Problems arise when the application does internal buffering but if data is written to the kernel then the page cache takes care that every process has the correct view of the data.

Comment: Add a `rm file` between both `exec` lines. You'll get an error because the filename no longer exists. This is not the case with the non-portable way using `cat "/proc/$$/fd/3"`, because once a file is open, it is not removed by `rm` (it will be removed once all the instances are closed).

Answer (score 4):

With ksh93, it is possible to seek:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh93
file='somefile'
exec 3<> "$file"
printf "%s\n%s\n" "foo" "bar" >&3
cat "/proc/$$/fd/3"
exec 3>#((0))
cat <&3
exit 0
```

I get:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

as wanted.

Comment: Although this might work, I can't expect `ksh93` to be installed on every machine. Thus, this is not really portable.

Comment: I'd replace `#!/bin/ksh93` with `#!/usr/bin/env ksh93`, you never know where the binary is located. On my system it's `/usr/local/bin/ksh93`, for instance.

Comment: @Marco OK, I've edited my answer to use `#!/usr/bin/env ksh93`. Concerning the portability, this depends on the context: a user or admin can generally install ksh93, while if the `/proc` file system is not provided by the OS, there isn't much one can do. BTW, one can hope that other shells support the ksh93 seek feature in the future. My RFE for zsh: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg00386.html

Comment: while perhaps not as convenient, the script need not necessarily be executed by `ksh` to take advantage of `ksh`'s awesome i/o handling. `ksh -c '3>#((0))'` should do in a pinch.

Comment: @mikeserv Or `ksh93 -c '3>#((0))'` because on some machines, `ksh` is another ksh implementation (e.g. `mksh`). Now, the best solution for the future would be to make other shells (bash and zsh, in particular) implement this feature.

Comment: You know what just occurred to me? What does one of those other shells do if, while reading a script on stdin like `sh -s <script` the command `ksh -c '>#((0))'` is read? Is that a hacky little `goto`?

Comment: @mikeserv Don't you mean redirecting stdin with `<#((0))` instead of `>#((0))`? Like this: `zsh -c "sh -s <=(echo \"echo OK; ksh -c '<#((0))'\")"`

Comment: @mikeserv Of course, I've tried. This outputs `OK` endlessly.

Answer (score 2):

You need `lseek` function to reposition file offset. It is not implemented in `bash`, so you need to write a basic program in `C` for that. An example of it, and some discussion can be found on [bash mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-12/msg00044.html):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    return lseek(atoi(argv[1]), 0L, 0);
}
```

Of course in such simple scenario as in question you can always just reinitialize descriptor

```
exec 3<> file
```

after `printf`, but that is obviously not general solution.

Comment: Requiring to compile a C program makes this solution not portable. Although this might work in theory, it's not a practical solution.

Comment: @Marco Perl is installed on most machines (if not all). So, you can use: `perl -MPOSIX -e 'lseek(3,0,0)'`

Comment: @Marco - compiling a C program should be portable to any POSIX machine - more so even than Perl. Why would you suggest it is not portable?

Comment: @mikeserv I think that the reason is that not all machines have a C compiler installed. Concerning `perl`, all Debian machines have it installed since it has standard priority.

Comment: @vinc17 - it's my understanding that a basic C compiler is part of the definition of a Unix system. Maybe I'm mistaken - but [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html#tag_20_11) is spec'd. Still, i'd be happy to know better if you do. I sometimes just use `cc` and a heredoc or a pipe to compile little utilities on the fly from stdin and run them. It's what I mean to do with this little cherry later *(thanks jimmij)*.

Comment: @mikeserv Most systems are not POSIX conforming systems by default, and in particular, some utilities may be missing. This may be the case of `c99` (and `pax`, which is even less likely to be installed). On a machine where I have an account: `-bash: c99: command not found` And `c99` isn't necessarily ISO C99 conforming in practice (in particular concerning floating point).

Comment: @mikeserv What you're saying is complete non-sense. It is a fact that most systems are not POSIX-conformant. If you disagree with this choice, you should report bugs. Perl is rather stable, in particular on something as simple as a `lseek`. End of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing some work on a file descriptor that you expect you'll want to read again, then you can portably do it in the body of a here-document:

```
exec 4<somefile 3<<plus
$(    printf %s\\n some random lines
        cat <&4
)
plus
cat <&3
```

The solution is not perfect perhaps - there is no portable way, for example, to seek back through the here document file descriptor. And the command substitution will elide trailing blank lines from whatever `cat` writes to stdout, but all of these problems are very simply handled.

In the first place, redirections are scoped to their containing compound command, and so it is a small matter to nest these a bit in a loop to handle any repetition you might require. It is also possible to implement a loop within the command sub itself - or even to call out to an interactive shell on `/dev/tty` if you want. But most generally I prefer to link a heredoc to a function definition.

```
fn() { : do something w/ fd3
} 3<<INPUT
$1
$(:gen some output;:maybe cat or head <stdin)
INPUT
while IFS= read -r line; do fn "$line"; done
```

It is also possible to read one heredoc another writes.

```
cat 4<<SAVED <<AND
$(  cat)
SAVED
$(  printf %s\\n some random lines
     cat <&4)
AND
```

Or you could loop like...

```
until test && cat <&4
do exec 3<&4 4<<IN
$(: gen output; cat <&3)
IN
done 4<infile
```

And of course you could call something like the `fn` above from within as well.

And regarding the trailing blank line problem - *if* it is a problem - then you can simply `echo .` at the tail end of the command sub, then make sure you strip the last line from the fd when you read it like `sed \$d <&"$fd"`.

But, while pretty secure, looping over files like this in the shell is usually a bad idea anyway - notice there is at least a fork per generated file? Shells assign fds and utilities handle them - do your loop in a `sed` or `awk` script and manipulate the file data w/ a standard utility then use the shell to direct it on output - that is usually best practice.