# Why doesn't sed exit immediately after writing the output?

Tags: sed, pv

I ran sed on a large file, and used the [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml) utility to see how quickly it's reading input and writing output. Although pv showed that sed read the input and wrote the output within about 5 seconds, sed did not exit for another 20-30 seconds. Why is this?

Here's the output I saw:

```
pv -cN source input.txt | sed "24629045,24629162d" | pv -cN output > output.txt
   source: 2.34GB 0:00:06 [ 388MB/s] [==========================================================================================================>] 100%            
   output: 2.34GB 0:00:05 [ 401MB/s] [              <=>                                                                                                           ]
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `strace`? I would guess it's done with its work but then you have to wait for buffers to flush before it actually exits. With `strace` you should see what it is up to.

Comment: Did you tried that: `sed -un "24629162q;24629045,24629162d;p"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons. In the first place, you don't tell it to `q`uit.

Consider:

```sh
seq 10 | sed -ne1,5p
```

In that case, though it only `p`rints the first half of input lines, it must still read the rest of them through to EOF. Instead:

```sh
seq 10|sed 5q
```

It will quit right away there.

You're also working with a delay between each process. So if `pv` buffers at 4kb, and `sed` buffers 4kb, then the last `pv` is 8kb behind input all the while. It is quite likely that the numbers are higher than that.

You can try the `-u` switch w/ a GNU/BSD/AST `sed` but that's almost definitely *not* going to help performance on large inputs.
 If you call a GNU `sed` with `-u` it will `read()` for every byte of input. I haven't looked at what the others do in that situation, but I have no reason to believe they would do any differently. All three document `-u` to mean *unbuffered* - and that's a pretty generally understood concept where streams are concerned.

Another thing you might do is explicitly line-buffer `sed`'s *output* with the `w`rite command and one-or-more named `w`rite-file[s]. It will still slow things a little, but it probably will be better than the alternative.

You can do this w/ any `sed` like:

```sh
sed -n 'w outfile'
```

`sed`'s `w`rite command is always immediate - it is unbuffered output. And because *(by default)* `sed` applies commands once per line-cycle, `sed` can be easily used to effectively line-buffer i/o even within the middle of a pipeline. That way, at least, you can keep the second `pv` pretty much up to date w/ `sed` the whole time like:

```sh
pv ... | sed -n '24629045,24629162!w /dev/fd/1' | pv ...
```

...though that assumes a system which provides the `/dev/fd/[num]` links *(which is to say: practically any linux-based system - excepting Android - and [many others besides](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123659/52934))*. Failing said links' availability, to do the same thing you could just explicitly create your own pipe with `mkfifo` and use it as the last `pv`'s stdin and name it as `sed`'s `w`rite file.

Comment: In this example `seq 10|sed 5q` How to exit without printing `5` I tried to `d`elete before `q`uite but it just deleting `5` and resumes `seq 10|sed {5d;q}`

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed `seq 10|sed 4q`