# How can the standard input of one program be passed as an arg to another?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, arguments

Let's say a program exists, which takes two arguments; input file and output file.

What if I don't wish to save this output file to disk, but rather pass it straight to `stdin` of another program. Is there a way to achieve this?

A lot of commands I come across on Linux provide an option to pass '-' as the output file argument, which does what I've specified above. Is this because passing the `stdin` of a program as an argument is not possible? If it is, how do we do it?

An example of how I would image using this is:

```
pdftotext "C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.pdf" stdin(echo)
```

The shell I'm using is bash.

Comment: `cat <file | cmd /dev/fd/0` works on most unices.

Comment: Not working for me. Tried it with:  `cat < README.txt | cp /dev/fd/0`. It said `cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/dev/fd/0’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.`

Comment: `program input-file /dev/stdout | another-program`?  Also note that `echo` reads nothing from stdin.

Comment: Yes, that was a botched example I came up with to illustrate my curiosity. Good point.

Comment: @Dziugas - of course not - you can't `cp` a file nowhere. `echo 1 2 3| cp /dev/fd/0 /dev/tty` will print `1 2 3`. And by the way, `/dev/fd/[num]` is more likely to work than `/dev/std(in|out|err)` in most cases. See [Portability of File-Descriptor Links](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123602/52934) about what you can expect to work where.

Comment: A good UNIX program would write to standard output leaving it up to the user to decide whether they wish to redirect to a file or pipe to another command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the program supports writing to any file descriptor even if it can't seek, you can use `/dev/stdout` as the output file.  This is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/1` on my system.  File descriptor 1 is stdout.

Comment: This solved my query. So is there no way to do it when the program needs to seek?

Comment: If you're trying to prevent disk access, you can write the file in /dev/shm/, however, if you don't want any file on the filesystem, then as far as I know, there is no way to seek on a pipe. Seeking forward means it would have to buffer everything in memory until it reached that point forward, and seeking backward implies having buffered everything in memory.

Comment: `pdftotext` like many (but not all) other utilities support `-` for that as well (which would work even on systems that don't support /dev/stdout, or where /dev/stdout don't work as expected like on Linux where stdout is not a pipe). `pdftotext file.pdf - | wc -c`

Answer (score 11):

From the `pdftotext` man page:

> If  text-file is ´-', the text is sent to stdout.

So in this case all you need is:

```
pdftotext "C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.pdf" -
```

Or if you want to pipe this to STDIN of another program:

```
pdftotext "C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.pdf" - | another_prog
```

---

Using `-` as substitute for a filename is a convention many utilities follow (including pdftotext) when we want input from STDIN or output to STDOUT.  However not all utilities follow this convention.  In that case the idiomatic way to do this in bash is to use a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
my_utility "C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.pdf" >( cat )
```

Here the `>(  )` behaves largely like a file passed to `my_utility`, but instead of being a real file, the stream is piped into the stdin of the contained process, i.e. cat.  So here, the text should ultimately output as required.

Use of `cat` almost always sets off [UUOC alarm bells](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html) on forums like this.  I contend that if the utility does not support `-`, then this is a useful use of `cat`, though if there are any ways to do this process substitution without the `cat`, then I'm all ears ;-).

However, if (as the question states) the ultimate destination of of the stream is STDIN of another program, then the `cat` can be eliminated:

```
my_utility "C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.pdf" >( another_prog )
```

Comment: And let me backpedal once more: if *`prog2`* writes to stdout, *`prog1 input_file `* `>( cat ) | ` *`prog2`* is better than *`prog1 input_file `* `>( ` *`prog2 `* `)`, because the `cat` form waits for *`prog2`* to complete (i.e., before the shell issues the next prompt or goes on to the next command (e.g., after `;` or `&&`)), while the `cat`-less form waits only for *`prog1`* to complete.  Also, after the `cat` form, `$?` is the exit status from *`prog2`*, whereas, in the other, `$?` is the exit status from *`prog1`*.  (You pays your money and you takes your choice.)

Answer (score 5):

If your shell supports them, the simplest way of doing such manipulations would be to use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution): `<(…)` and `>(…)`. This works in bash, zsh and ksh and possibly other shells. For example:

```
$ sort <(printf "b\nc\na\n")
a
b
c
$ ls
foo
$ cp <(find . -name foo) bar
$ ls
bar  foo
```

However, this won't help in the example you state since `pdftotext` will save in a text file. While your best choice (apart from the obvious one of using `-`) is to use `/dev/stdout` as suggested by @TiCPU, you could also use another shell feature. The construct `!:N` refers to the Nth argument of the previous command. Therefore, you could do:

```
$ pdftotext "C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.pdf"  out.txt
$ cat !:2
```

Comment: When is `cat <( ` *`command `* `)` ever useful?  That looks like a UUOC.  I think TiCPU's answer is correct (although not spelled out clearly): `pdftotext "C BY K&R.pdf" /dev/stdout`.  (I guess Digital Trauma's answer would work, although it's also a UUOC.)

Comment: @Scott yes, it is a UUOC but neither of my other two examples are. I very often use `<()` for things like `diff <(sort foo) <(sort bar)`. As for `cat <(command)` specifically, I can't think of a case at the moment that couldn't be replaced by other tools but there may well be one. In any case, `cat` was just the example chosen by the OP.

Comment: I don't see where the OP chose `cat`.  Somebody posted a semi-answer featuring a UUOC in a comment, and the OP (who didn't understand quite how to apply it) replied that it didn't work for him.  (And, of course, I realize that commands that ***don't even include `cat`*** cannot be UUOCs.)

Comment: @Scott whops, true, it was the `echo(stdin)` which I translated to `cat`. That's just the only way I could think of to twist the OP's example into something workable.

Comment: While I agree that `cat <()` can be useful in some situations, in this scenario however it is not working at all. The problem (very poorly described by OP, I must admit) is that `pdftotext` takes two arguments: *input file* and *output file*. If second argument is missing then it produces nothing, so `cat <(pdftotext "file.pdf")` would also return nothing. One can cheat `pdftotext` command by giving `>(cat)` as a second argument like Digital Trauma answered, but `cat <()` is pointless here. Obviously in `pdftotext` case it is best just to use `-` as the output file name.

Comment: @jimmij ah, I see. In that case, TiCPU's answer is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Scott How is my answer a UUOC?  How would you do this process substitution without cat?  `>(  )` will effectively pipe the stream to whatever process is inside - so we actually do need a `cat` here to output that stream.  Normally we should be able to do something like `pdftotext input.pdf -`, but apparently `pdftotext` doesn't support the `-` parameter to output directly to stdout instead of a file - try it.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma it is not uuoc. I believe cat is the fastest you can get in case of just printing, but in fact you can use other command as `>(grep something)` to be more useful. BTW, my `pdftotext 3.04` **do** support `-` as an output file, so I'm a little surprised by the whole discussion.

Comment: @jimmij yes - I did not notice that pdftotext actually supports `-`.  In this case I think it is a UUOC ;-)  But I think the construct is still useful for utilities that don't support `-`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Yeah, sorry; I was just in the process of typing a retraction.  But first: The question *seems* (to me) to be asking how to handle some (hypothetical) program (nominally, `pdftotext`) that insists on doing `open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)` and `open(argv[2], O_CREAT|O_WRONLY)`, and doesn’t default to reading stdin or writing stdout (not even if given an arg of **`-`**).  And TiCPU and Digital Trauma both wrote decent answers to that question.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And I want to retract what I said in my first comment: if TiCPU’s answer doesn’t work (e.g., because `/dev/stdout` doesn’t exist), Digital Trauma’s answer may be the only (or at least the best) answer, and calling it a UUOC, while arguably, technically true, was a little harsh, because, while *`prog1 input_file `* `>(  cat  ) | ` *`prog2`* *can be* abbreviated to *`prog1 input_file `* `>( ` *`prog2 `* `)`, the `cat` form is (again, arguably) clearer.

Comment: Of course, if you just want to *display* the output of *`prog1`*, you can use *`prog1 input_file `* `/dev/tty`, or jas's idea, *`prog1 input_file `* `$(tty)`.

Comment: @Scott Thanks - These comments were useful - I've significantly revised my answer - I hope its much more complete now.

Comment: @terdon I hate to be a stickler, but this doesn't seem to work.  Specifically it is no different that running `pdftotext "C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.pdf"`, which puts the output in a file called `C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE.txt`, but none of the text is output to STDOUT for piping to another program.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma that's not being a stickler! That's me being an idiot. Thanks for pointing it out and please never apologize when pointing out mistakes. I would much rather have my mistake pointed out to me and so learn something than leave it there in all its dubious glory.

Answer (score -2):

```
cmd tty
```

`tty` returns the name of the terminal connected to `stdout`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, which is about combining commands; perhaps you expand with an example of how you would achieve that.

Comment: I guess you are saying to check with `tty` the name of the terminal, and then use that file as an output, for example `pdftotext file.pdf /dev/pts/2`. In that case, I agree.

Comment: That can be abbreviated/automated to *`prog1  input_file `* `$(tty)`; which is generally going to be equivalent to *`prog1  input_file `* `/dev/tty`.  But this approach assumes that the goal is to display the output of *`prog1`* (i.e., in the terminal), and that is not what the question is asking (see [the comments](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217112/how-can-the-standard-input-of-one-program-be-passed-as-an-arg-to-another#comment368930_217157) on [terdon's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217157/23408) for some clarification on the meaning of the question).