# Grab standard input/ouput of a running process under FreeBSD/macOS

Tags: process, osx, freebsd, open-files

Under Linux I often use `/proc/<pid>/fd/[0,1,2]` to access `std[in,out,err]` of any running process.

Is there a way to achieve the same result under FreeBSD and/or macOS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425340/how-can-i-capture-the-stdout-from-a-process-that-is-already-running) for a dtrace based answer to this. I've tested it on FreeBSD and it works perfectly:

```
    capture() {
        sudo dtrace -p "$1" -qn '
            syscall::write*:entry
            /pid == $target && arg0 == 1/ {
                printf("%s", copyinstr(arg1, arg2));
            }   
        '   
    }
```

Comment: works great ! thanks and sorry for the delay.

Comment: how can I write to the stdin of the running process?

Comment: How can I capture stdin of a running process (stdout works like above) on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

[procfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procfs&sektion=&n=1) is also available in FreeBSD but from the man page it seems that `fd` is not implemented. Procfs is usully only used in FreeBSD for Linux compability.

The native replacement of procfs on FreeBSD is [procstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procstat&sektion=1) which you can use with the `-f` parameter to get the file descriptor:

```
procstat -a -f
```

Another native tool to identify active files is [fstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fstat&apropos=0&sektion=0). Remember `-m` for memory mapped files if needed.

```
fstat -m
```

If you like to work through the file system then we have [devfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devfs) which exposes [fdescfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fdescfs&sektion=5) and you can access [fd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fd&sektion=4) in the manner you request.

```
ls /dev/fd
```

Example:

```
echo -n Hello > hello.txt
echo " World!" | cat hello.txt /dev/fd/0
```

If you want something which is portable across system to Mac as well - then you could use the tool [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) (LiSt Open Files) which available as a [package](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/lsof/).

If portability is of concern you should read [Portability of file descriptor links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links). It covers all bases.

Comment: Describing `procstat` as a replacement for `procfs` seems inaccurate to me. The initial commit for it [here](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=174199) described it as providing "some
of the missing functionality from procfs(4) and new functionality for
monitoring and debugging specific processes." It wasn't meant to replace `procfs`, which existed in FreeBSD then and still exists.

Comment: procfs for sure has its merits but it is not mounted by default for a reason. Procfs has not seen a lot of maintanence since and personally I would not rely on it for other than legacy reasons. But no - it is not officially deprecated. See some of Robert Watsons reasoning here https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2007-November/022228.html

Comment: I think, I miss something, when I use procstat -a -f I get the tty that launched it for exemple in my current test /dev/pts/2 , and I know I want fd1. But I can't put everything together. Can you provide an exemple? In my test (open cat in an xterm) I suppose the interesting line is : 56604 cat                  1 v c rw------   7    1788 -   /dev/pts/2 But I can't simply tail -f /dev/pts/2, maybe I should try reading from the 1788 which is the offset or something similar.

Comment: It is not quite what you are going for but you can monitor your pseudo terminal using [watch](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?watch) like `watch /dev/pts/0` or `cat /dev/pts/0 | tee -a pts0log`. Or going Python with [psutil](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/py-psutil) `psutil.Process(pid=PID).get_open_files()`. Understand the comment from Steve why he thought calling `procstat´ a replacement was inaccurate. It is not a 1:1 replacement.