# Linux memory usage?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory

We have 1TB of memory on a server which hosts an SAP application.

When the app is running the memory usage shown in `top` is around 700GB. When the app is stopped the memory usage shown in `top` comes down to 10GB. A reboot of the server gets the memory usage to 1GB.

- Even though no application is running, why does `top` show 10GB used and gains 9GB after reboot?
- Is it possible to gain that 9GB without a reboot?

Output of `free -g`:

```
free -g 
                 total used   free shared buffers cached 
Mem:              1009  567   442    0      0     152 
-/+ buffers/cache:      415   594 
Swap:              1     0     1
```

Comment: First things first, have you read http://www.linuxatemyram.com/? Next, please provide the output of `free` and even better, `/proc/meminfo` during each of these data points.

Comment: What does the output of `free` show in these scenarios? It's likely that the 10G is still being shown as in use due to buffers and cache.

Answer (score 5):

Linux uses RAM in a different way from what other operating systems do.

Rather than sitting there with unused RAM, Linux stores data that it *thinks* might be used in RAM-any applications may be cached here, files, etc.

As a result, Linux RAM usage is higher than what is used by running applications. This extra usage is buffered to be sued by other things. Run `free -h` and the second row under **used** will show you that a lot of the "used" memory is really just cached.

In the case where all of your memory is cached and a program needs memory, it will remove enough from the cache to fit that program.

Comment: Windows has a filesystem cache as well. It's itemized differently but it's still shown in Task Manager.

Comment: But I agree. Op is probably just looking in the wrong field for their free memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to some file descriptors still open though the app is stopped. You can list the open file descriptors using the techniques mentioned [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html).

If you need to close the file descriptors without rebooting, you can follow the approach mentioned by Graeme [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123430/47538).However, you need to be aware of the file descriptors that you are closing as highlighted by Graeme in his answer. His answer is,

> To answer literally, to close *all* open file descriptors for `bash`:
>
> ```
> for fd in $(ls /proc/$$/fd); do
>   eval "exec $fd>&-"
> done
> ```
>
> However this really isn't a good idea since it will close the basic
>   file descriptors the shell needs for input and output. If you do this,
>   none of the programs you run will have their output displayed on the
>   terminal (unless they write to the `tty` device directly). If fact in
>   my tests closing `stdin` (`exec 0>&-`) just causes an interactive
>   shell to exit.
>
> What you may actually be looking to do is rather to close all file
>   descriptors that are not part of the shell's basic operation. These
>   are 0 for `stdin`, 1 for `stdout` and 2 for `stderr`. On top this some
>   shells also seem to have other file descriptors open by default. In
>   `bash` you have 255 (also for terminal I/O) and `dash` I have 10 which
>   points to `/dev/tty` rather than the specific `tty`/`pts` device the
>   terminal is using. To close everything apart from 0, 1, 2 and 255 in
>   `bash`:
>
> ```
> for fd in $(ls /proc/$$/fd); do
>   case "$fd" in
>     0|1|2|255)
>       ;;
>     *)
>       eval "exec $fd>&-"
>       ;;
>   esac
> done
> ```
>
> Note also that `eval` is required when redirecting the file descriptor
>   contained in a variable, if not bash will expand the variable but
>   consider it part of the command (in this case it would try to `exec`
>   the command `0` or `1` or whichever file descriptor you are trying to
>   close). Also using a glob instead of `ls` (eg `/proc/$$/fd/*`) seems
>   to open an extra file descriptor for the glob, so `ls` seems the best
>   solution here.
>
> #### Update
>
> For further information on the portability of `/proc/$$/fd`, please
>   see
>   [Portability of file descriptor links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links).
>   If `/proc/$$/fd` is unavailable, then a drop in replacement for the
>   `$(ls /proc/$$/fd)`, using `lsof` (if that is available) would be
>   `$(lsof -p $$ -Ff | grep f[0-9] | cut -c 2-)`.

Comment: OP is asking about memory, not disk space.

Comment: @Patrick, oh ok. So, the problem is more likely due to the open file descriptors right? I mean, the memory is not released due to some open file descriptors. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Well one if the primary confusions in this subject is caching. However caching comes into play whether file descriptors are opened or not.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks. so caching and file descriptors are not related in any way, is it?

Comment: Generally no they are not.

Comment: this is what free -g shows now when the app is running, but i need to wait till the app is shutdown to give the output of free later

Comment: abc:/usr/sap/ABC/>  free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1009        567        442          0          0        152
-/+ buffers/cache:        415        594
Swap:            1          0          1